# What is the smallest uniquely hamiltonian graph with minimum degree at least 3?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs

I would like to know more about uniquely hamiltonian graphs with minimum vertex degree at least 3, and in particular what is the smallest one.

(Recall that a graph is *hamiltonian* if it has a cycle passing through each vertex exactly once, and is *uniquely hamiltonian* if there is only one such cycle.)

Here's the smallest one that I currently know.

[image]

Does anyone know if a smaller one (fewer vertices) has been published?

***Added years later (2023)***

With almost any extremal question in Hamiltonicity the Petersen graph crops up and this is no exception.

This picture shows that the graph can be partitioned into two 9-vertex induced subgraphs, each obtained by deleting a vertex from the Petersen graph and then joined by four judiciously chosen edges.

The graph can be shown to be uniquely Hamiltonian by arguing in the "half-graph" about how paths can connect the four "terminals" (vertices with edges to the other side).

[image: Minimal UH3 Graph]

Comment: What are the numbers placed for? They definitely don't indicate the cycle (which is obvious). Do they bear some additional info?

Comment: The numbers are just an arbitrary labelling so no further information there.

Comment: A google search brings up this article: http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-39636-1_1. And it claims there is such a graph on only 10 vertices.

Comment: @Wolfgang This is a very strange paper. I agree that it claims that there is such a graph on 10 vertices. However it does not actually contain any graphs, except for a diagram (Figure 1) of a 10-vertex graph that is not uniquely hamiltonian. The paper spends almost all its time on an extended description of a search algorithm that judging by the number of acronyms used must be quite complicated, and plenty of tables of running times and success rates etc. But no uniquely hamiltonian graphs :-(

Comment: Aha, figured it out. The 10-vertex graph in the aforementioned paper has the property that it has an edge that is contained in only one hamilton cycle. This means it can be turned into a uniquely hamiltonian graph via a simple doubling procedure. So while the 10-vertex graph itself is not uniquely hamiltonian, it leads to a 20-vertex example that is.

Comment: According to A004108 (Number of n-node unlabeled connected graphs without endpoints) there are "only" 9808209 graphs to check on 10 vertices.  Might it be possible to generate these efficiently, and then check for a unique hamiltonian cycle?

Comment: If you have access to it, [*A census of maximum uniquely hamiltonian graphs*](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgt.3190050313/abstract) by Barefoot and Entringer claims in the abstract to provide an algorithm for constructing maximal uniquely Hamiltonian graphs of order $n$.

Comment: @MartinRubey It is easy to generate the 10-vertex graphs (maybe 3-4 seconds), a few thousand times slower to check them for unique hamilton cycles, but overall an easy computation.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The Barefoot/Entringer paper (which I can only see if I actually walk to the library, which I have not yet done) is concerned with u.h. graphs with $n^2/4+1$ edges. The 2 such graphs on 10 vertices each have two vertices of degree 2 and I believe this pattern continues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The system encouraged me to answer my own question, although it feels a bit strange to do so.

Anyway, after a bit of thinking and a (more substantial) bit of computing, I can now safely conclude that this 18-vertex 28-edge graph is the smallest uniquely-hamiltonian graph with minimum degree 3, and there are no others of this order (number of vertices) and size (number of edges).

Comment: Is there any description of this graph other than giving a list of its edges?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes, there is a nice description - two copies of $P-v$ connected together appropriately, where $P$ is the Petersen graph. I can't draw pictures in comments so I've added the diagram to the question.

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure what the smallest such graph is, but since you also asked for more information on uniquely hamiltonian graphs with minimum degree $3$, [Entringer and Swart](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895680900878) proved the following nice theorem.

> For each $n= 2k, k \geqslant 11$, there exists a uniquely hamiltonian graph on $n$ vertices having two vertices of degree $4$ and all others of degree $3$.

Comment: Yes, I came across this paper, and wondered whether their 22-vertex example might be the smallest, which really started me off on trying to find the smallest. My guess is that my 18-vertex example is the smallest, but I haven't confirmed this yet. I do know that it is the only one with this number of vertices and edges.